# Get value after last comma by formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A2:

```
96610,80508,64406,48305
```

How do I extract the last value, in this case 48305?

There must be an easy solution, but I can't come up with it.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be something like

```
=regexextract(A2&"", "[^,]+$")
```

or, to convert the output to a number:

```
=regexextract(A2&"", "[^,]+$")+0
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

This formula did it:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",500)),500))
```